# How to break from loop which iterate over a Subprocess.Popen stdout?

Tags: python

I'm using the below subprocesss to read lines from a quite large file (arnd 4 GB)

```
p1=subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p=subprocess.Popen(gawk_exp, shell=True, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

where cmd = zgrep "text to search" filename.gz

gawk_exp is just another gawk expression to filter from the grepped lines.

and then iterating on the p as follows:

```
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
   ..
   ..
   ..
   if(success):
      break
```

This results in "grep: writing output: Broken pipe" error.

But I'd like to exit early from the for loop if it satisfies certain condition.

I've tried many avenues like,

```
if(success):
    os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
    os.kill(p1.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
    OR
    subprocess.Popen.kill(p1.pid, p.pid)
    subprocess.Popen.kill(p.pid)
    OR
    p1.stdout.close()
    p.stdout.close()
```

in different order, but no avail.

Any hint on how can I gracefully break from loop?

Version details:
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Jun 11 2009, 14:09:37)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)] on linux2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `stderr` for the `zgrep` job, capture it, and only print what it wrote there if you detect an error elsewhere (e.g. if you never make it to the early exit in your loop).

Or, stop using `Popen` to run `zgrep` and start using `zlib` straight in Python: http://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html - personally I'd give this a try, followed by possibly implementing the whole thing in Python instead of using `gawk`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not answering your question directly here, but I'd just point out that for these kinds of tasks, [plumbum](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is very useful.  Using it instead of `popen`, etc., would make your life so much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately I can't use it as I'm bound to use 2.4.3.